# extjs panelgrid alternative

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, accordion

Going through the ExtJS documentation I got lost among the names and couldn't find the components I needed. I'd like to show the properties of an object like this:

> Name: name
>
> Address: address

With JSF, I would use a panelgrid with outputText tags. Is there a component like that?
And there's something else: I'd like to make this panel "closeable" like an accordion or something like that so the user could hide the information if not needed, but I couldn't make the accordion panel's size adapt to the content. When I used an accordionpanel in primefaces  the panel was resized if the content changed. Is there any way you can do this with ExtJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, how about this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    collapsible: true,
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: So it's called colapsible... Thank you that part works. :) Rendering the properties though I'd like show simple key value pairs. I wouldn't like to put them into a table because there will be one row only and it doesn't look good.

Comment: @Peter If you just want to display a handful of properties of just one object I would hardcode it into the html property like `html: '<div class="yourstyle">Name: ' + obj.name + ' Address: ' + obj.address + '</div>'` You can also use a **[XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate)** but for just one row thats already to much.